# F# Async.Map not found

Tags: f#, onvif

I have source from http://sourceforge.net/p/onvifdm/code/HEAD/tree/

When I try to build this solution, I get the following issue in the `onvif.utils` project.

```
use! response = request.AsyncGetResponse() |> Async.Map(fun x-> x:?>HttpWebResponse)

Error: Method or object constructor 'Map' not found
D:\Working\onvifdm\onvifdm-code-96-trunk\onvif\onvif.utils\OdmSession.fs
```

Comment: This function is defined here in your project: http://sourceforge.net/p/onvifdm/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/utils/utils.fsharp/extensions.fs#l95 so if it can't find it then there must be a problem with the project files or something.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a function that extends Async, taken from a useful source on [understanding map](https://sidburn.github.io/blog/2016/03/27/understanding-map).

```
module Async =
    let map f op = async {
        let! x    = op
        let value = f x
        return value
    }
```

Which has a type signature `('a -> 'b) -> Async<'a> -> Async<'b>`

For example -

```
let onInts = async { return 1 }
```

... is an `async<int>`, and ...

```
let onStrings = Async.map (fun x -> x.ToString()) onInts
```

... produces an `Async<string>`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use following code as a replacement:

```
let! webResponse = request.AsyncGetResponse()
use response = webResponse:?>HttpWebResponse
```

Also you can write your own extension to Async type - here is an [example](https://github.com/tpetricek/FSharp.AsyncExtensions/blob/master/src/Async.fs) how it can be done. All you need is to implement high order function for the code above.

Answer (score 0):

For those still looking for an answer to this, the problem is that Async is referencing the wrong class. Change it to Microsoft.FSharp.Control.Async and the problem should be resolved.

Comment: Nope, `Microsoft.FSharp.Control.Async.map` still gives me `'map' is not defined`

Answer (score 0):

if this is still an open question, let me suggest using FsToolkit.ErrorHandling:
[https://www.nuget.org/packages/FsToolkit.ErrorHandling]
It contains an Async.map implementation and a lot of useful features to deal with Result.

As an alternative I think this should work:

```
use! response = request.AsyncGetResponse() |> async.Bind (fun x-> x:?>HttpWebResponse |> async.Return)
```

Comment: Please edit the answer with your comment.